# does "char *" and "String" return type for a function is same?

Tags: c++

in this code, if i replace "**char ***" by "**string**" as a function return type, keeping entire code as it is, will it work?

```
char* sum_str(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int lenS1 = strlen(s1);
    int lenS2 = strlen(s2);
    char* newString = malloc((lenS1 + lenS2 + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    while(i < lenS1)
    {
        newString[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(i < lenS2 + lenS1)
    {
        newString[i] = s2[i - lenS1];
        i++;
    }
    newString[i] = '\0';
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: How about you try it?

Comment: Did you give it a try? What were your results?

Comment: The C tag for this question is erroneous and I have removed it.  It makes no sense for C which has no `string` type in its standard library.

Comment: You are using a very old C++ compiler. The line `char* newString = malloc((lenS1 + lenS2 + 1) * sizeof(char))` is legal (and perfectly valid) in C but is illegal in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work<sup>1</sup>, but that doesn't mean that a `char*` and `string` return types are the same.

What happens is that `std::string` can be implicitly constructed from `char*`. So you return a new `string` instance, which owns its copy of the data pointed at by the `char*`. It is (almost) the same as saying this:

```
std::string s = newString; // newString is your char*
return s;
```

Bear in mind that you have to call `free` on `newString`.

The way to concatenate strings in idiomatic C++ would be

```
std::string s1 = ....;
std::string s2 = ....;
std::string s3 = s1 + s2;
```

<sup>1 Except that you will have a memory leak. You will have to call `free` on `newString` before returning the string.</sup>

Comment: in my turbo c even if i include "cstring.h" it gives error if i use "string" anywhere in the program. so i cant try this code :(

Comment: @Priyanka `std::string` is in standard header `<string>`. But you need a reasonably modern compiler, that is standards compliant. This is old stuff, so anything implementing C++98 should do.

Comment: @Priyanka From which museum did you get this Turbo C? :-O

Comment: How can you say that this will work? I'm not downvoting, but a simple `s/char\*/string/g` (which is how I interpret the question) results in code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @DavidHammen the question is clearly only about this code and speaks only about replacing the return type, not every occurence of `char*`.